# Slim 4 Routing - Object Not Found

Tags: php, routes, slim

I am pretty new to Slim so any pointers would be very helpful.

I have trying to set up something simple that routes to different .php templates I have created.

This is what I have:-

Index.php:

```
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;
use Slim\Views\PhpRenderer;
use Slim\Handlers\Strategies\RequestResponseArgs;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';



$app = AppFactory::create();
    
$app->setBasePath((function () {
    $scriptDir = str_replace('\\', '/', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
    $uri = (string) parse_url('http://a' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?? '', PHP_URL_PATH);
    if (stripos($uri, $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) === 0) {
        return $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    }
    if ($scriptDir !== '/' && stripos($uri, $scriptDir) === 0) {
        return $scriptDir;
    }
    return '';
})());

$app->get('/', function ($request, $response, $args) {
  $renderer = new PhpRenderer(__DIR__);
  return $renderer->render($response, "index_Template.php", $args);
})->setName('profile');


$app->get('/search', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $renderer = new PhpRenderer(__DIR__);
    return $renderer->render($response, "search_results.php", $args);
  })->setName('profile');

$app->run();
```

When I go to http://localhost:8080/App/ I get the index_Template.php as I expected.

But when I hit http://localhost:8080/App/search I get an Object Not Found! Error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you use Apache? Can you show your htaccess files?